# how to access various mongo databases with node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I need some help with this question.

I try to build an node express REST api which has to deal with various mongoDB databases on the same mongoDB server.

What is the right approach to do this?

The sequence could be:

- app starts
- connect to the mongoDB Server
- use the right express route
- check which database is needed
- finally query the correct data
- connection to the database is still open

OR

- use the right express route
- connect to the mongoDB Server
- check which database is needed
- query the data
- close the DB connection

AND how can I do this with mongo-native driver, not mongoose?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In Mongo, database connections are persistent - that is you should leave a connection open and not close it until you want to close your server.

Assuming you're using the new Mongo driver (new as in, not 3 years old), it will handle reconnects and managing the connections for you - all you have to do is just connect to it once the server starts and close the connection when the server ends.

This is a property of the node driver - so it is equally true for the driver itself and wrappers/mappers like Mongoose.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I understand the current mongo-native driver (2.0.33) opens once a persistent connection to a mongo server and database, but how can I switch to an other database on the same server with the same persistent connection?